# Apple Mail app notification settings keep resetting to defaults

Tags: mail.app

I've traditionally eschewed the Apple Mail app in favor of other apps, but Outlook is too bulky and I am tired of using the Outlook and Gmail web interfaces to check my various accounts. I have 5 different email accounts (a couple of them are spam accounts) set up in the Apple Mail app. I created a smart mailbox called "Primary mailboxes" that only shows the inbox notifications for the accounts that I care about (ignoring the two spam accounts that I have). For some reason, the "New message notification" setting keeps resetting from the smart mailbox (Primary mailboxes) back to "Inbox only" even though I didn't make any changes in settings. The result is that I've not been getting any notifications. I only end up seeing the dock unread count. [image]

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this one. I have come up against exactly the issue you describe.

Comment: No luck on this one. I couldn't find anything else online describing this problem or the solution to it. :/